# Estimating read time for an R Markdown document and printing it possibly below the title

Tags: r, r-markdown

System: Windows 10, RStudio 1.0.153, R 3.4.1

I write blog posts in R Markdown. I would like to use Medium's approach of including an estimated reading time for the blog post just underneath the title, because research has suggested that [including reading time in your blog post increases the likelihood that people will read it all](https://marketingland.com/estimated-reading-times-increase-engagement-79830). To estimate reading time I would like to use a simplified version of [the algorithm used on Medium](https://blog.medium.com/read-time-and-you-bc2048ab620c):

1. compute the number `N` of words in the document, preferably excluding the YAML preface and the R code chunks with `echo=FALSE`, i.e., all the text that my visitors won't see)
2. compute the number `m` of imported images and R-generated plots: if counting plots makes the problem too complicated, it's ok to count only imported images. I import each image separately in its own R chunk with the `include_graphics` function, thus even just counting the number of occurences of the `include_graphics` keyword would work.
3. estimated time in minutes is

   `seconds <- N/200*60+12*m
   minutes <- round(seconds/60)
   fin <- ifelse(minutes>1, " minutes", " minute")
   estimation <- paste0("Estimated reading time: ", minutes, fin)`

The code for the estimation should be executed each time the R Markdown  doc is knitted, so ideally inside an R chunk in the R Markdown doc itself, or in an external function which is then sourced in an R chunk. This way, the estimation would automatically update as I edit the R Markdown document. How can I do that? For example, given the sample R document below, which has `N=106` words and `m=2` images, the text

```
"Estimated reading time: 1 minute"
```

should be be included in the HTML output, just below the title, author and date.

Sample R Markdown document:

````
---
title: "Testy test"
author: "anonymous"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r load_data, echo=FALSE}
include_graphics("doge.jpg")
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

Comment: Did you look at `blogdown` and `hugo` ? The number of words and reading time are part of the system core. You may find the answer in the code. Or you can switch to hugo....